# I got a error for setting up microphone for speech recognition on Windows 11

Tags: audio, windows-11, microphone, speech-recognition

I got a error for setting up microphone for speech recognition on Windows 11.

I got an error from speech recognition troubleshoot, **settings -> time language -> microphone start**.

```
(Error description)
Package ID: SpeechDiagnosticCalibrate
Path: C:\Windows\Diagnostics\Index\SpeechDiagnostic.xml
Error code:0x80004003
Source: engine
Context: Admin Privilege
```

My pc recognize the microphone from **device manager** and can record sound with **"windows voice-recorder."** But it can not recognize voice with **windows speech recognition, google voice search, and alexa app**.

Please tell me how to set up speech recognition.

Comment: The error is from **windwos speech recognition troubleshoot**. I can not run as admin.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and error code when trying to run the speech recognition through Settings. Somehow, opening it via Control Panel worked for me:

**Control Panel > Ease of Access > Speech Recognition**

Then hopefully you can set up the mic and speech recognition.

You can also try right-clicking on the sound icon in the taskbar > Sounds > Recording > right click on your mic > Configure Speech Recognition.

Hope that worked!